# Bluetooth framework for older iOS devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, compatibility, core-bluetooth

My question is related with Bluetooth technology around iOS.
I've watched WWDC about Bluetooth Low Energy 101, what's new, the basics etc, and about using the CoreBluetooth framework available in iOS 5 and later.
I've looked through different sites and documentations trying to find more information about Bluetooth 2.1 and 4, but there is so few.
GameKIt is not an answer, I am developing an app to work with an non-iOS device.
Some of the topics I've went through:

[Connecting to a Bluetooth device from iOS, no MFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955278/connecting-to-a-bluetooth-device-from-ios-no-mfi)

[iOS - How to integrate bluetooth devices in my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090298/ios-how-to-integrate-bluetooth-devices-in-my-app)

http://www.bluegiga.com/files/bluegiga/Presentations/BT4_0_for_Apple.pdf

[Bluetooth 4.0 with older Bluetooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004171/bluetooth-4-0-with-older-bluetooth)

[IPhone Bluetooth Connectivity to Non IOS Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071516/iphone-bluetooth-connectivity-to-non-ios-devices)

But the supported devices are just 4S and up and latests iPads...

1) will the latest CoreBluetooth framework just fail on older devices?

2) Did apple have any frameworks for BT 2.1 or something? What to do, there are still so many ipad2 and iphone4 users, I can't just ignore them..  So what framework actually to use?

Any help, advice, idea,link will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well...
You need to understand one thing: ***CoreBluetooth framework*** is used for *Bluetooth Low Energy* and ***ExternalAccessory framework*** for the *"Classic" Bluetooth*. It is really two kind of different approchs of what we usually call Bluetooth (as a simple user/consumer).
Only recent iDevices support *Bluetooth Low Energy* (iPhone from 4S, MacBook Air from 2011, etc.). That's why it doesn't support *iOS4* for example.
For your information, Bluetooth Low Energy is kind of a fork of Bluetooth which appears only in Bluetooth 4.0. Even if having a Bluetooth 4.0 device does not ensure that it supports Bluetooth Low Energy (as I said, it's a fork which is not always include).
As a simplistic vision, Bluetooth Low Energy works like a NSDictionnary with a NSDictionnary in it. You get a *Peripheral*, which as one of more *Services* which has one or more *Characteristics*. Quite different from a common device, right ?

Answer (score 3):

> Did apple have any frameworks for BT 2.1 or something? What to do, there are still so many ipad2 and iphone4 users, I can't just ignore them.. So what framework actually to use?

To talk to a Bluetooth 2.1 device, you need to be in the Made for iPhone accessory program. The details of it are under NDA, but you should expect things like Apple reviewing your manufacturing processes and auditing your accounts, and putting a custom chip into the accessory. If you don't make the accessory yourself, you're probably out of luck.

The only exceptions are the classes of device that iOS supports natively: keyboards, audio output, car stereos, other iPhones etc. However, you still can't send and receive arbitrary data, you're limited to using whatever APIs exist for the specific functions (e.g. for audio output, Core Audio lets you set a few properties for how Bluetooth devices behave).

Comment: Thanks!  But are you sure that If i sue 4.0 framework it won't be able to speak with 2.1 device without that permission?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Without jailbreaking, there's no other way to talk to 2.1 devices.

Comment: Allow me to double check something else: I meant a non-iOS device, like a sport gear or smth.

Comment: Yeah, the point stands — if it's a Bluetooth 2.1 device, the only way you can use it is if the device is part of the Made for iPhone program. Lame's answer is describing the ExternalAccessory framework, which is how you talk to Made for iPhone accessories.